# Remove a specific item from a list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a specific ID that exists in a list of IDs, here's the code of the ID and the list

```
var idClient = $('.popup-chat-header').attr("id"); // a client ID

// loop through a list of ID
$('#clientList li > a').each(function(){
    var newIdList = $(this).attr("id"); 
});
```

I have tried :contains() Selector, `(newIdList:contains(idClient)).remove()`, but it seems im not implementing it the right way? any tips is appreciated!

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you wanting to remove a specific item in a JavaScript array, or do you have an array of jQuery HTML elements where you want to remove a specific item?

Comment: NEVER use the id twice or more

Comment: @joshuam i have an array of jQuery HTML elements where i want to remove a specific item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this instead of the $.each loop:

```
$('#' + idClient).parent('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID of the element to remove, this is all you need:

```
$('#id').remove();
```

An example jsFiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/RLLR2/

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your selector like this

```
$('li#clientList > a').each(function(){

        });
```

Also you better use class, ID's should be unique in the page.

IF you use class then better try this

```
$('li.clientList > a').each(function(){
            var newIdList = $(this).attr("id"); // this should give you the ID of all the DOM with class clientList
        });
```

Comment: id have to be unique, this selector is not necessary `$('#clienlist > a\')`